# Formatting a decimal column into euro currency

Tags: oracle

I need to format a decimal value into a string with the format ###.###,##.

I've already tried:

```
SELECT to_char (11230.3423, '999,990.00') FROM DUAL
```

I'll get 11,230.34  where i want 11.230,34.

If i change the format as:

```
SELECT to_char (11230.3423, '999.990,00') FROM DUAL
```

I'll get an error.

Note: I need to format Euro(€) values so decimal separator is ','.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT to_char (11230.3423, 'FM999G990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: You don't actually need the escaped quotes in this context - `'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'` is valid and slightly simpler. (You do need the quotes for `alter session`, but not here.)

Comment: Ok oracle documentation of [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) states the need of single-quotes, but nice to know that it works without them as well...